# User authenticate play framework

Tags: authentication, playframework

Like many others in here I'm following the documentation about authentication on the documentation in here:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/JavaGuide4

Everything was ok until I got to the part of implementing the validate function.

```
public String validate() {
            user=User.authenticate(email, password);
            if (user == null) {
              return "Invalid user or password";
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Am I suppose to implement the User class? import some library that I'm not aware of?

I'm new at play so please forgive my ignorance!,
and many thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes you have to implement the User class. Same tutorial, two pages before, https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/JavaGuide2.

Comment: Oh, looked and haven't seen. Thank you!